# callSingle() Throwing cached result is an exception

Tags: karate

Getting callSingle() cached result is an exception while calling bearerToken.feature file which is used in karate-config.js file when tried to call this feature file it's working local but getting this issue in devops pipeline

GetBearerToken.feature file

Karate-config file

```
function fun() {
karate.configure('ssl', true);
karate.configure('report', {
    showLog : true,
    showAllSteps : false
});

const baseUrl = '';
const apiUrl = karate.properties['api.url'] ?? `${baseUrl}/admin/api`;
const bearerToken = karate.callSingle('classpath:websakrunners/GetBearerToken.feature', {
    authURL      : karate.properties['auth.url'] ?? `${baseUrl}/identityserver/connect/token`,
    clientId     : karate.properties['auth.client_id'] ?? 'auto',
    clientSecret : karate.properties['auth.client_secret'] ?? 'auto1234',
});
```

const config = {
accessToken                                          : bearerToken.finalBearerToken
};

return config;

}

Comment: really sorry but these kinds of issues are impossible to diagnose remotely. try upgrading to karate 1.4.1.RC4 and also refer some guidelines for callSingle(): https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karatecallsingle